# How to create a list out of a class?

Tags: python, function, class

Let's say I have a class named Books that has the variables: author, title, and book_id. And then I have another class name Patrons that has the variables: name, patron_id, and borroweds.Borroweds is supposed to be a list of Books currently "checked out" so I would have to encorporate the class Books into the class Patron. But how would I go about doing that?

This is what I have so far:

```
class Book:
    author= ""
    title = ""
    book_id= ""
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, author, title, book_id):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.book_id = book_id      
    def __str__(self):
        s = str("Books("+str(self.author)+", "+str(self.title)+", "+str(self.book_id+")"))
        return s
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
class Patron:
    name= ""
    patron_id= ""
    borroweds= list()
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, name, patron_id, borroweds):
        self.name= name
        self.patron_id= patron_id
        self.borroweds= borroweds
    def __str__(self):
        s= str("Patron("+str(self.name)+","+str(self.patron_id)+","+list(self.borroweds)+")")
        return s
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
borroweds = [Book('Author Authorsson', 'The book of books', 'ISBN76576575757')]
patron = Patron('thename', 'theid', borroweds)

>>> patron
Patron(thename,theid,[Books(Author Authorsson, The book of books, ISBN76576575757)])
>>> patron.borroweds[0]
Books(Author Authorsson, The book of books, ISBN76576575757)
```

Also, skip the class attributes, you don't need them.

```
class Book:
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, author, title, book_id):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.book_id = book_id      
    def __str__(self):
        s = str("Books("+str(self.author)+", "+str(self.title)+", "+str(self.book_id+")"))
        return s
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

class Patron:
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, name, patron_id, borroweds):
        self.name= name
        self.patron_id= patron_id
        self.borroweds= borroweds
    def __str__(self):
        s= str("Patron("+str(self.name)+","+str(self.patron_id)+","+str(self.borroweds)+")")
        return s
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Comment: Also, how does this use Books in Patrons?

Comment: @user2829177: You don't need the attributes because you don't need the attributes. It's like asking why you don't need to put a cow in the fridge when you are making a chocolate cake: Because you don't need to.

Comment: @user2829177 My code above makes a list of Books (admittedly only one book, but it is still a list), and puts that as the `borroweds` attribute in Patrons. I think you may be over thinking this, it is really very simple. :-)

Comment: @user2829177 I added an example that might clarify this.

Comment: @user2829177 I think you are not overthinking, I think you are not aware of there difference between class variables and object variables. [Check out this link for more information](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-and-object-vars.html).  Otherwise simply use your implementation of `Patron`and try this: `print Patron.name`. An empty string will be printed, no matter what objects you made. Now take Lennarts code and try the same. It will throw an exception, but if you try `print patron.name` it will print `thename` just like Lennart instantiated the patron object.

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the typo in the __str__ method of Books? Your parenthesis at the end needs moved left, after `self.book_id`.

You don't need the class attributes because they are for "global" purposes for every 'Patron'. So if you wanted to keep track of how many patrons you make, you could update that "global" variable each time you make one, like this:

```
class Patron:
    patron_id= 0
    # the class constructor
    def __init__(self, name, borroweds):
        self.name= name
        self.patron_id=self.patron_id
        self.borroweds= borroweds
```

Every time you create a Patron object you could add one to the class attribute:

```
p1 = Patron('Dave',[Book('Me','Something', '8675309')])
print p1.patron_id
Patron.patron_id+=1
p2 = Patron('Dave',[Book('You','Others', 'Number9')])
print p2.patron_id
```

You'll notice the class attribute was changed and set the objects attribute. You could even create a class attribute in `Patron` that was a list of every `Patron` object and add each one during the __init__ method if you wanted. Its going to keep track of it for the class.

Also, I think you need `","+list(self.borroweds)+")"` to be `","+str(self.borroweds)+")"`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why I don't need the attributes. I wanted to make the borroweds as a list of books borrowed so wouldn't I need to use list()?

Comment: borroweds should be a list, but that list is passed into `Patron` as a list and does not need to be called a list again like you may see in C# or something. See [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-nzzVa/2/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096) for a quick run through. You then must call str() on that list which returns what you defined in the `Book` class \__str__ method, as a string, in order to concatenate everything in your \__str__ method for `Patron`.